# Drupal views recipe for displaying Civievent Participants using a jump menu selector

Tags: civievent, drupal, drupal-views

I managed to do this once before, but can not remember how to do it again.  I'm still new to all this.

I need to display a list of participants for all active events using Drupal Views with a Jump Menu selector.

I have managed to create a view showing a table of current participants grouped by event title. But now I need another Views page that shows a jump menu containing the name of the event and and the number of attendees.  When I select an event and push the go button, a table showing the names of the attendees for that event are displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Exposed Filter in your view -> and if you also have Better Exposed Filter module installed - then you have some more configuration options like bypassing the Apply button.

Comment: Thanks KarinG, but unfortunately I am such a newbie that I am unsure what that means.  Could anyone provide a list of steps that would be required?

Answer (score 1):

There was an explanation using JumpMenu on Stack Exchange [here](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/p4j5ugyrfjg33dajc47iq31kpr) but you need to sign up to see it.

Quoting mattwire

> google was eventually my friend.  It works by creating a view as a block setup as a jump menu (select list) which you setup to filter on all the valid records.  You set the output of the field to rewrite as a path which matches the  path of the second view which has a contextual filter setup to use the parameter passed in via the path. Using a jump menu and contextual filters gets me what I want with two views

Comment: Thanks, but this link needs a login, is there another link elsewhere?

Comment: yes it does, sorry, but given that chat.civicrm.org is the other place where a lot of civi discussion takes place it may be worth you signing up.

Comment: tried to be more helpful by putting his comments in as quote

Comment: if you want to grill him for more detail then joing chat.civicrm.org would be a good step